# WinRT Replacement for System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

It doesn't look like `TypeConverter` is available to use. What is recommended to replace this?

I was going to go and create my own `TypeConverter` class to use to replace it, but if there is a new or better way in WinRT to do it, I'd go that route. There are also many other classes that I would need to recreate; like all the default type converters.

Comment: `TypeConverter` is actually a pretty complex API, especially when you consider all the upstream plumbing; For winrt, yes: it is pretty minimal - so: to answer you question we'd need to know what set of scenarios you need to support.

Comment: Converting a string to any built-in type and back to a string. This is where all the built-in converters, like `StringConverter`, will come into play. I'm also using `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` and any other classes used around these. I could implement just the features from these I need by creating a "MissingFromRt45" set of classes, but it looks like the list of classes will be quite large.

Comment: Do you think it would be more beneficial to pull out all the `TypeConverter` stuff I'm using and change it to a custom type conversion setup? That way it will work no matter what version of .NET it's running on.

Comment: that would be my recommendation, yes. I feel your pain: I have libraries that work on CF, regular .NET, Silverlight, Portable, Xna, RT, etc. It can be a PITA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **TypeConverter** class in the WinRT and the team has not announced any plans to include it in a future release. You have a number of options.

**Option 1:** If the conversion is to be done as part of a data binding use the **IValueConverter** interface as Dennis mentioned.

**Option 2:** If you are the creator of the type you can add your own explicit or implicit operators to support casting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xhbhezf4(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.80).aspx

**Option 3:** You could create your own TypeConverter class.

**Option 4:** (The way I'd do it if not part of a binding) You can add your own extension methods:

```
static public class ConverterExtensions
{
    static public string ToFixedString(this double value)
    {
        return value.ToString("D");
    }
}
```

Which would let you write code like this:

```
double d = 123.45;
string str = d.ToFixedString(); // str now equals "123"
```

Comment: If the goal is to only replace the use of TypeConverter in XAML declarations, which of these options is preferable?  I've tried #1 unsuccessfully, and #4 is out.

Comment: I would be really interested how you implement option 3. I can't find any typeconverter example in uwp. Also there exists a uservoice https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9576897-implement-system-componentmodel-typeconverter-in-w

Comment: With the creators update typeconverters are coming! http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2017/02/15/implement-type-converter-uwp-winrt-windows-10-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) interface.

Comment: Are there any built in converters that implement this interface?

Comment: WinRT is more Silverlight, than WPF. So, I don't think, that there are any out-of-the-box converters.