# Using Google drive .Net Apis in Windows 8 Application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, google-drive-api

I have created Created a Windows 8 Store App Blank Page Added the Google drive .dll files in reference of the project and then Cleaned and Build the Solution.
I am getting [Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter in module System.dll" error.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like the dlls you added aren't valid for the .NET profile for Windows 8 apps since it doesn't include TypeConverter. You might need to look for different dlls, different SDK or roll your own.

Comment: Unfortunately Filip Skakun is right. It's not possible to use the TypeConverter in the ComponentModel since it's not a part of WinRT, and there is no known plans for it getting included. For clarification please see the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495937/winrt-replacement-for-system-componentmodel-typeconverter

Comment: @Filip: Is there any SDK that supports it?