# InputScope dependency property, XAML designer problems + errors

Tags: xaml, uwp, dependency-properties, inputscope

I have a control that consists of a button and a textbox.

I wanted to set the input scope of the textbox, so I introduced a new dependency property:

```
public InputScope InputScope
{
    get { return (InputScope)GetValue(InputScopeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InputScopeProperty, value); } // Notify prop change
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty InputScopeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(InputScope), typeof(InputScope), typeof(SearchControl), new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue));
```

In XAML:

```
<controls:SearchControl InputScope="Number" /> <!-- etc... -->
```

(Obviously assigning it to the InputScope property of the textbox in the style of this custom control.)

**My problem:** While this works, the numeric keyboard gets shown when focused, but I have blue underline in the XAML, and also an error message: The TypeConverter for "InputScope" does not support converting from a string.

Is there a way to fix it without a dirty hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to fix it without a dirty hack?

You could implement a type converter. Please refer to Tim Heuer's blog post for more information and an example:

**Implementing a type converter in UWP XAML:** http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2017/02/15/implement-type-converter-uwp-winrt-windows-10-xaml.aspx

You may also want to read this:

[WinRT Replacement for System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495937/winrt-replacement-for-system-componentmodel-typeconverter)